# Excel VBA Paste Values with Offset

Tags: vba, excel

How do I paste values from E2:AJ11 into the active cell on another worksheet?

I.e. the user selects a cell on Worksheet2 > VBA copies E2:AJ11 from Worksheet1 and pasts everything into that cell.

The following VBA pasts everything starting A1 into Worksheet2, but I need it to paste into the active cell.

```
Sub Paste()

Worksheets("WS1").Range("E2:AJ11").Copy Destination:=Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1)

End Sub
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: How is this code executed?  If before you run this macro the user already selects cell "B2" on the second worksheet, and then this macro is run, the values will be pasted starting at cell B2.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm hoping to accomplish. There will be a button on Worksheet2. The user selects B2 on Worksheet2 > clicks the button > VBA pasts values to B2.

Comment: I just tested this, the only way its getting pasted starting at A1 on worksheet 2, is if you actually select A1 on the second worksheet before running the macro.  Just select another cell on the second worksheet before running this. Then again I'm not sure how this macro is exactly called in your VBA script so there might be something on how it is called that's giving you the behavior youre seeing.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Hmm, maybe I should try a different approach. The values in E2:AJ11 will be different each time the user needs to past them to Worksheet2. So, the 1st set of copied values should go to D2 on Worksheet 2, the next set will go to D12, etc. The user will need to use the button to run the code, each time when the correct values are in E2:AJ11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your cell where you want to paste and press button.

Code would have copy ActiveCell at end i.e.

```
Worksheets("WS1").Range("E2:AJ11").Copy ActiveCell
```